# Foreign Key not Responding while fetching, Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am making a Django Project, A Business Directory.
In which while fetching data from DB, I am unable to fetch the data related to Foreign Key,
Please help

my models.py is::

```
from django.db import models


class Directory(models.Model):

    Bussiness_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=900)
    Number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Web_url = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    Catogory = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Bussiness_name

class Adress(models.Model):
   directory =  models.ForeignKey(Directory)
   adress_name =  models.CharField(max_length=300)
   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.adress_name

class Photos(models.Model):
   directory =  models.ForeignKey(Directory)
   Photo_path =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Photo_name =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Photo_name
```

My view.py is ::

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from crawlerapp.models import Directory
from crawlerapp.models import Adress
from crawlerapp.models import Photos
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    Directory_list = Directory.objects.all()
    t=loader.get_template('C:/Python27/django/crawler/templates/crawlertemplates/index.html')
    c = Context({'Directory_list': Directory_list,})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

def contactus(request):
    Directory_list = Directory.objects.all()
    t=loader.get_template('C:/Python27/django/crawler/templates/crawlertemplates/contactus.html')
    c = Context({'Directory_list': Directory_list,})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

def search(request):
    if 'what' in request.GET and request.GET['what']:
        what = request.GET['what']
        crawlerapp = Directory.objects.filter(Catogory__icontains=what)
        return render(request, 'C:/Python27/django/crawler/templates/crawlertemplates/search.html',
                  {'crawlerapp': crawlerapp, 'query': what})

    elif 'who' in request.GET and request.GET['who']:
        who = request.GET['who']
        crawlerapp = Directory.objects.filter(Bussiness_name__icontains=who)
        return render(request, 'C:/Python27/django/crawler/templates/crawlertemplates/search.html',
                  {'crawlerapp': crawlerapp, 'query': who})

    else:
        message = 'You submitted an empty form.'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

When I am trying to fetch data from my DB(MySQL), It is only fetching the data of the class Directory, form Models.py

And the code I used in html page for fetching is::

```
<p>You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>

{% if crawlerapp %}

    <p>Found {{ crawlerapp|length }} in this Category{{ crawlerapp|pluralize }}.</p>
    <ul>
        {% for Directory in crawlerapp %}
        <li>Business Name:  {{ Directory.Bussiness_name }}</li>
        Description:        {{ Directory.Description }}</br>
        Contact Number: {{ Directory.Number }}</br>
        Web_URL:          {{ Directory.Web_url }}</br>
        Adress:               {{ Adress.adress_name }}</br>
        Photo:                 {{ Photos.Photo_name }}</br></br>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No Business matched your search criteria.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The OutPut I am getting is somewhat like below

like for example:  You searched for: computer repair

```
               Found 1 in this Categorys

               Business Name: C S Tecj
               Description: hello
               Contact Number: 098754
               Web_URL: www.rrrrrr.co
               Adress: 
               Photo:
```

Please help me to fetch the data for the foreign keys, that is Adress: and Photo: ,too

Please help to solve this.

Comment: You are going to run into issues for using absolute paths for template rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `ForeignKey` objects in the reverse order like this:

```
{% for Directory in crawlerapp %}
<li>Business Name:  {{ Directory.Bussiness_name }}</li>
    Description:    {{ Directory.Description }}</br>
    Contact Number: {{ Directory.Number }}</br>
    Web_URL:        {{ Directory.Web_url }}</br>
    Adress:         {% for Adress in Directory.adress_set.all %}{{ Adress.adress_name }}</br>{% endfor %}
    Photo:          {% for Photos in Directory.photos_set.all %}{{ Photos.Photo_name }}</br>{% endfor %}</br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: define the project root directory and remove the absolute links to the  template

Comment: Please solve that path problem toooooooooooooooooooo
please.........................

Comment: Just create a new question. Someone should be out there to help you out.